# Many-To-Many relationships with Postgresql and accesing them

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, postgresql

I'm working with a Posgtgresql database about movies, and I have a few Many-to-Many relationships like the following one:

There's a table with movies and each movie has some keywords, as well as two movies can have the same keyword. For that we have three tables: `movies`, `keywords`, and `movies_keywords`.

The table named `movies` is self-explanatory, it contains the title, an ID and many attributes that a movie has.

The table `movies_keywords` has two columns: a movie ID and a keyword ID. This is like the "middle" that connects the two other tables.

Lastly, the table `keywords` contains a keyword ID and the corresponding keyword.

The problem is the following: I'm working with Django and I need to access all the keywords for one movie, but they're not *directly* connected, there's this middle point that doesn't let me access the  names. Do you have any idea how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this is models.py (the relevant part)

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    (...)
    director_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'movies'

class MoviesKeywords(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keywords, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'movies_keywords'

class Keywords(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'keywords'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.keyword)
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: models.py you mean?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @MartínSchere yes post your models

Comment: @iklinac Yes, i know the many-to-many relationship, but that doesn't include the use of Postgres, does it?

Comment: @MartínSchere ORM is database unspecific, you can use many-to-many ( you have specific case where you have created through table manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to your first model ( also model table names should be singular in django -> [code style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/) )

```
class Movie(models.Model):
      ...
      keywords = models.ManyToManyField('Keyword', through='MoviesKeywords', related_name='movies')
```

Afterwards you can access data as in [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) document

```
movie = Movie.object.filter(pk=1) 
keywords = movie.keywords.all()
```

Comment: I'm trying that out